# Android Animation - Why does fromXDelta has a negative value?

Tags: android, android-animation

I have two animations borrowed from the [Android Jetpack Navigation Codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-navigation#5). These are the following ones:

```
// slide_in_right.xml>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="400"/>
</set>
```

With a little research I have understand this one. It translates from the right of the screen to the left of the screen. Got it.
But now, I have this one:

```
// slide_in_left.xml
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="-100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="700"/>
</set>
```

Why they have given `fromXDelta` the value -100% ?? What does that mean ?

Comment: If +100% is one full width to the right, then -100% is one full width to the left :) So it slides in from the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How I understand the two cases

#### `fromXDelta=100%`

Translate the view exactly one screen-width to the right

#### `fromXDelta=-100%`

Translate the view exactly one screen-width to the left

Comment: Thanks. Basically, it is the opposite. I created a little project for testing and now I understand it better.